# Guest can't create product programtaically [ similar to wishlist ]

Tags: magento-1.9, login, session, product-view, popup

If the **Registered user** click on "save design" button we are  **creating new product.**

**Issue** : But if **guest** user click on "save design" button, we are displaying pop up box to register or login. once guest user logged in, **new Product is not creating****

**controllers**

```
protected function _createProduct($type, $doSave=true, $originalProduct, $newImagePath="") 
{       
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');

        $product->setName($originalProduct->getName()); 
        $product->setDescription('what ever you need here');

        $customerId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerId();
        $product->setCreatedByCustomerId($customerId);      

        if ($doSave)
            $product->save();

        return $product;
    }
```

**Edit**

Now we can able to **create new product once guest user click on button**, but guest user is not logged in and we need to assign the Created product to **Guest user** similar to **Registered user**

```
<?php if (!Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()): ?>
    <div id="ajaxlogin-login-window" style="display: none;">        
            <span><?php echo $this->__('Login into your Account 4') ?></span>

       <form action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('example/amasty/createSimpleProductAndRedirect', array('_secure'=>(!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS']==='on'), 'id' => Mage::registry('current_product')->getId())) ?>" id="ajaxlogin-login-form">
            // form code login/Register in pop up box
        </form>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            //<![CDATA[
            var ajaxLoginForm = new VarienForm('ajaxlogin-login-form', true);
            jQuery("#ajaxlogin-login-form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (ajaxLoginForm.validator.validate()) {
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: jQuery('#ajaxlogin-login-form').attr('action'),
        }).done(function(result) {
            alert(result);
        }).fail(function() {
            alert('There is some error saving your design.');
        });
    }
});
            //]]>
        </script>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: I mean which session related code i need to take from  `function  loginAction()` & add to `function _createProduct`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

what happens in wish list product , when a guest is adding a product to a wish list in the preDispatch method on controller they are checking whether the customer is logged in or not. If customer is guest then they set the current product's url customer session like this

```
Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->setBeforeWishlistUrl($this->_getRefererUrl());
```

so we can do the same here.

As i can see in the code that there you are creating a product and then setting the `CreatedByCustomerId` attribute of the product. so what we can do here is set the `CreatedByCustomerId` to some value and then save the product after that we can set the product id in the session and set the `setBeforeAuthUrl()` to a custom controller and **redirect to the login page.**

After the customer has logged in , customer will be taken to our custom controller which we had set in `setBeforeAuthUrl()` we can get the product id from customer session  and load the product and set the `CreatedByCustomerId` to customer id as customer id and then save.

Comment: Thanks, if you can  update an answer with related code, that will be really helpfull.....

Comment: Also Instead of redirecting to login page, we are displaying `pop up box to login or register`....

Comment: Sure.. will try to come back with code

Comment: Is it possible to acess front end of site m

Comment: please click [link](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/custom-apple-iphone-4.html)

Comment: I tried on your site. What i noticed is that if i register a new customer after creating design and clicking save ,the page gets refreshed and created image is lost. I didnt tried the same with login but it am assuming the same should happen.What we can do here is instead of showing popup to login/register for guest users we can redirect them to our controller and in that controller we can save the image and create product and then redirect them to the login page and after login redirect them to our another controller and get the product previously created and set customer id and save it again

Comment: but client requirement in to show pop up instead of redirecting to another page, is there any chance we can save the image with pop up only ?

Comment: Yes we can ! but in that case we will have to stop the page refresh when login/signup is successfull and if customer registration/login is successfull send the request to save image  manually

Comment: okay, i will try to remove page refresh and let you know.....

Comment: as in `Add to wishlist` feature also after login , user will redirect to wishlist page, in our case is it mandatary to remove `refreshing page after login` to achieve what we want ?

Comment: please check `edit` part in question....

Answer (score 2):

The way I would solve this is to listen to the generic controller `predispatch` event.  I would then filter out for only my specific controller.  Then check if the customer is logged in and if not, I'd store the data that you want in their session.  Then let it flow normally for the login sequence.  After the user logs in, I'd check to see if there is data in my session that should create the product and follow that workflow from there.

**etc/config.xml**

```
<frontend>
    <events>
        <controller_action_predispatch>
            <observers>
                <my_module>
                    <class>my_module/observer</class>
                    <method>onControllerActionPredispatch</method>
                </my_module>
            </observers>
        </controller_action_predispatch>
    </events>
</frontend>
```

**Model/Observer.php**

```
class Observer
{
    public function onControllerActionPredispatch($observer)
    {
        if (
            $observer->getEvent()->getControllerAction()->getFullActionName() == 'my_module_controller_action' &&
            !Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()
        ) {
            Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->setMyModuleCustomProductInfo(
                $observer->getEvent()->getControllerAction()
                    ->getRequest()->getPost('my_namespace')
            );
        }
        else if (
            Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn() &&
            Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getMyModuleCustomProductInfo()
        ) {
            // Either forward to a new action, or call your helper/model methods to do what you want.
        }
    }
}
```

In the above example, if the customer posts to your custom method and isn't logged in, the data is stored in the customer session and then they proceed to the login page (or the login form is shown).  After they've logged in, if they have the custom data stored in the session, then you can either automatically create the product and add it to their cart, or forward them to an action that will do that for them.

Comment: Thanks , can you please tell how i can find values of `my_module_controller_action` & `setMyModuleCustomProductInfo` , so that i will replace correct values and check.....

Comment: If you just add the observer, you can output `$observer->getEvent()->getControllerAction()->getFullActionName()`.  It's just your a string of your module prefix, the controller, and the action, all lowerecased.  For example, if in my XML I defined blocks for my module as: `<blocks><my_customModule><class>My_CustomModule_Block</class></my_customModule></blocks>`, then your module prefix is: `my_moduleName` (the same name you'd put before the `/` when referencing blocks/models/helpers).

Comment: So if I had a controller `My_CustomModule_ProductController` and the action is `addCustomProduct` then the full action name is `my_custommodule_product_addcustomproduct`.

Comment: i tried your code in observer.php as `echo $observer->getEvent()->getControllerAction()->getFullActionName(); ` , after i ran observer.php file in browser as in [link](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/app/code/local/Amasty/Example/Model/Observer.php) , but it gave blank page....

Comment: we have module like this image, please check : http://prnt.sc/etbemv

Comment: also according to this image, i got action name as : http://prnt.sc/etbgwn : amasty_example__createProduct

Comment: That's because your config is wrong.  (a) You should only have one `<events>` node under your `<frontend>` node in `etc/config.xml`.  So you can take the `controller_action_predispatch` node and move it so it's next to this node: `checkout_cart_product_add_after`.  (b) Secondly, `my_module` is a placeholder. You need to replace that with a reference to your actual module name.  In this case, replace all `my_module` references with `amasty_example`.  The white screen is probably because it's looking for `my_module` and not finding it.

Comment: The action name should be something like: `amasty_example_<controller_name>_<action_name>` where **<controller_name>** is either "index", "amasty" or "mydesign" and **<action_name>** is whatever action you're trying to run as an all lowercase string without the "action" suffix that all Magento actions have.

Comment: sorry, i am asking too much..... 1) action name : `amasty_example_amasty__createProduct ` [ as we have protected function _createProduct ]   2) also i replaced `setMyModuleCustomProductInfo` by `setAmastyExampleCustomProductInfo` , observer.php : https://pastebin.com/zJdzzdG9 , config.xml : https://pastebin.com/kDhrEmrn

Comment: seems i am missing only in finding correct value for `setMyModuleCustomProductInfo()` as i replaced to `getAmastyExampleCustomProductInfo()` i guess this is wrong....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56682/discussion-between-baby-in-magento-and-brett).

Comment: Actions cannot be protected methods of a class, only public ones.  You need to use the action name of the controller which calls that protected method.

Comment: please check `edit part` in question.....

Answer (score 1):

At first, find action call after click "Save Design" Button.
It will be controller ofc.
Then rewrite (or change) function by adding similar code on sunction start:

```
$isLoggedIn = Mage::helper('customer')->isLoggedIn();
if (! $isLoggedIn) {
    $this->_redirect('customer/account/login');
}
```

Comment: Thanks, now instead of redirecting to login page, we are displaying pop up once we click on `save design`..... but issue is we need to save product after login.....